# ruby save file from client to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, save

Imagine, I have this text on client:

```
<form action="{{ some action }}">
  <input type="file" name="certificate_template">
  <input type="submit" value="AAAeee, send me to server!">
</form>
```

What should I do to save this client file to server in folder named "uploads"?

Answer (score 0):

You need the form to have a post action, and in the corresponding post route in your controller execute the logic to save to file- Ruby's built-in [File class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html) should have the methods you need, although you will obviously need some way to verify that the uploaded file is not malicious.

Answer (score -1):

I found awnswer here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html chapter 5.1.